# Grid Hide Column Control that adjusts SQL query

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, gridview, nonfactors-mvc-grid

I'm doing a project in Asp.net Core 2.1 (EF, MVC, SQL Server) and trying to find a grid control (or tutorial or anything really, preferably free) that not only hides columns in the UI grid, but remembers which columns are hidden and then tweaks your SQL queries accordingly so you save the data cost on subsequent trips to the database.

Originally, I envisioned the user going into a separate page or modal to define which columns they want visible which would then bring back the appropriate query (and columns). However, I'd like to not reinvent the wheel if I don't have to.

I was looking at something like Angular Grid UI:
http://ui-grid.info/

They allow you to hide columns on your grid, but it appears the columns are only hidden at the UI via CSS or javascript manipulation? ...and nothing is really adjusted with the actual query? I could be totally wrong about that?

Then this one looks promising? It doesn't look all front end at least?
https://github.com/NonFactors/MVC6.Grid

The biggest problem for me is understanding how the data is gathered. It all just seems magical.

Anyone have experience with the above controls and know if it's possible with either of those? Or, is anyone aware of something that will do like I described above?

I'll have around 25 possible columns and imagine the user will only want to see about half to 3/4 of that (and won't change much). So, a ~50+% savings seems worth it as far as I know...

If you're extension, etc had that kind of efficiency, I think it would be pointed out in the features, but I'm not seeing it... or in the documentation. Thanks.

EDIT: To address Mark's comment below, there will be no paging. It will essentially be a ledger of transactions that user's can manipulate and then does calculations and such on that ledger. They will also be able to filter by date and time, or type and other criteria. So it could be a handful of rows or could be hundreds or even thousands.

Comment: This is subjective, but I like DataTables (good documentation/examples/support) and they have an example to [Show / hide columns dynamically](https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html) and also has [State saving](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html).  As to bandwidth savings, I'm not convinced it's worth the effort - especially if you implement paging and response compression.

Comment: Good point, there will be no paging... I updated the question to clarify more of what I'm doing. Thanks for your thoughts and suggestion, I'll give it a look for sure....